# Debug.Assert() only triggers when stepping over it

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, debugging, assertions

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 to write a .NET assertion:

```
Debug.Assert(false, "Testing Debug.Assert");
```

When I put a breakpoint on this line of code, wait until the breakpoint hits, and then let the program continue to run, everything works fine: an "Assertion Failed" dialog pops up. However, when I remove the breakpoint and rerun the application, the Debug.Assert() statement is simply ignored.

Does anyone have an idea what might cause this very strange behavior?

Comment: Are you 100% certain you're running the debug version? I know this is a potentially stupid question - but I've done this myself many times.

Comment: When you "rerun the application" are you running it in the debugger, or not? (F5 or Ctrl-F5?) Are you using an Express edition by any chance?

Comment: Yep, I'm running the debug version. When stepping over the Assert-statement the assertion dialog pops up, but not if I run the application without stepping through the code.

Comment: Regrettably, rebuilding the app doesn't help.

Comment: I'm debugging with the debugger attached. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Professional.

Comment: This should not happen, you are overlooking something. Can you reproduce it with a Console app and _just_ that line?

Comment: I've just retested it with a new WPF application with only a button that calls the Debug.Assert() statement, and I get exactly the same behavior.

Comment: Try rebooting the PC. If that doesn't work, rebuild it.

Answer (score 3):

A colleague of mine immediately knew what the problem was. I had to enable the "Enable Just My Code" flag at "Visual Studio 2010 / Menu / Options / Debugging / General". Apparently this is a [bug in Visual Studio 2010"](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/687333/debug-assert-cannot-popup-a-dialog-in-visual-studio-in-the-wpf-project).

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing the same problem. Using `Trace.Assert` works as expected.

---

Well, `Trace.Assert` started exhibiting the same behavior on the next debugging session.

---

Ah, found the problem.

- With 'Enable Just My Code" checked.

  - If 'Thrown' is checked for 'Common Language Runtime Exceptions' in
    the 'Exceptions' dialog (Ctrl+Alt+E), the Assert will be thrown.
  - If unchecked, the Assert will be thrown.
- With 'Enable Just My Code" unchecked.

  - If 'Thrown' checked, the Assert will not be thrown.
  - If 'Thrown' unchecked, the Assert will be thrown.

Therefore, the Assert will not be thrown when 'Enable Just My Code' is unchecked and 'Thrown' is checked for 'Common Language Runtime Exceptions'.

Comment: Same behavior happened to us in VS 2013, but even with "Enable Just My Code" checked.

Comment: Where can I find this "Thrown" thing in the Exception dialog? I see no such entry there? What is the full name of the exception we need to uncheck?

Answer (score 0):

The answers given here did not help but I found out that it was as simple as checking the "Define DEBUG constant" option for the Debug configuration in the project's build settings:

[image: The Define DEBUG constant option in project's build settings]